# help with pseudocode and looping

Tags: loops, pseudocode

PSEUDOCODE

```
Inventory service class

public class Inventory

    // declarations

    private itemnumber : integer
    private originalprice : integer

    public Inventory ()
        itemnumber = 0
        originalprice = 0
        return

public Inventory (ite : integer, ori : integer)
    itemnumber = ite
    originalprice = ori  
    return

public integer getitemnumber( ) 
    return itemnumber


public integer getoriginalprice( ) 
    return originalprice

public void setItemnumber(integer ite) 
    itemnumber = ite
    return


public void setOriginalprice (integer ori) 
    originalprice = ori
    return

End Class

Public class PayReport
```

Comment: It would really help those trying to help if you could change the formatting of your code. Surround it with backticks (i.e. \`code\`) and indent. :) **Edit:** Indent, not backticks. Then you can indent.

Comment: @Andrew: But not both! Indenting for blocks, backticks for inline text.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that the iv part is kind of misleading.  I think the intent was to read a file that contains inventory item[s] where each item is on a separate line.  So you would have one method that would read the file and in that method iterate over each line in the file and add an inventory item.  Maybe that is wrong but seems the most likely...  Or is that not the question for #1?

As for the looping, I'm not understanding exactly what you are asking.  You could just hard-code 7 (for the 7 days) or have a separate member something like numDaysOfSale then just loop over that and do the percentage calculation in that loop.

Hope that helps a little...
- Dave

Comment: For the looping am I doing it correctly or not since it says to decrease the price by 10 percent for the next 7 days.

Comment: Yeah IV in question 1 is misleading and I am still confused what to do, when I create a object/method do I list the original items or what, I have question marks for that section.

Comment: OK, I can't figure out how to format this so if some else can please do:

OK, so for the loop I would say something like this would be a little better:
'code'
...
onePrice = (read(Inventory.txt))  // Here you have "primed the read"
while onePrice is not at end of file
  // Print out onePrice

  // Read the next onePrice.
  onePrice = (read(Inventory.txt))
endwhile
'code'

Comment: okay so this would be the new format right (editing it right now).

Comment: For IV, I don't see the question marks (sorry if I missed them, been working all day), but it seems the teacher just wants you to read items from a file then print them out so maybe on a separate lines just print out the item name, the day #, then the price at that day making sure to print out the item and the original price (without the day #).  Since the teacher didn't specify what the output should look like that seems reasonable to do.

Comment: alright I'll update my editing part so it matches with what your saying.